# GitHub publish action failing, not able to find package.json in the root even if it is, not able to publish my node package with the action

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, github-actions, package.json

I've created a publish.yml file for a project and I want that on pushing to main branch, the package gets published to both npm and github packages. But not able to do so.

Below, publish.yml

```
name: Publish

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 16

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Publish to GitHub Packages
        run: npm publish --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Publish to npm
        run: npm publish
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
```

Error failing logs are:

```
Run npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/runner/work/depextract/depextract/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/work/depextract/depextract/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2023-07-15T11_32_46_065Z-debug-0.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 254.
```

My Package: [Depextract](https://github.com/ashutosh887/depextract)

Tried everything that I could do
Updated the Actions, publish.yml and even modified the package.json and package-lock.json.
Nothing seems to be working for now.

Answer (score 2):

Before doing basically anything with the code in GitHub Actions, you must checkout into the repo. The action for that is [`actions/checkout`](https://github.com/actions/checkout).

```yaml
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 16

      - ...
```

Comment: Yes that one got resolved but now it's stuck here Sir ==>>

npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in to https://npm.pkg.github.com/
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2023-07-15T11_55_54_952Z-debug-0.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.